# How can we tag the different Polaris games?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

I have just bought a new RPG called Polaris so I looked up the [polaris](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polaris) tag on the site to see if there were any questions about it. All of the results appear to be for another game called Polaris which is very different.

In fact there appears to be three Polaris RPGs, which RPG Geek disambiguates as:

- [Polaris (French RPG)](https://rpggeek.com/rpgfamily/17710/polaris-french-rpg) — originally published in 1997, with the third edition published in 2008.
- [Polaris (English RPG)](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/601/polaris-english-rpg) — published 2004 by Sean Dobes; official site apparently defunct
- [Polaris](https://rpggeek.com/rpgsystem/22146/polaris) — a game system taking its name from [*Polaris: Chivalric Tragedy at Utmost North*](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/602/polaris-chivalric-tragedy-utmost-north), the game that launched it. The other games in this system appear to not use the word Polaris in their title: [*The Starlit Kingdom*](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/33474/starlit-kingdom) and [*Thou Art But A Warrior*](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/22138/thou-art-warrior).

The Polaris tag's description currently corresponds to this last entry.

How can we tag these games so that we can tell which is which?

Comment: My naive first guess would be to include the publisher in the tag title for games that otherwise have identical names, but this specific case might be soluble by renaming the existing polaris tag to include the subtitle ("Chivalric Tragedy at Utmost North") and let the more simply named and newer Polaris RPG have "polaris". There are only a handful of questions in the existing tag so it wouldn't affect much.

Comment: @Carcer [polaris-chivalric-tragedy] fits well within our 35 character limit, so that seems very likely for that case. :)

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks for the edit, I should have done that myself.

Comment: @mwarren Happy to help! I had to dive in to research this and felt I should share what I'd found.

Comment: @Carcer: You should leave that as an answer so people can vote on it :)

Comment: @V2Blast fair enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest that:

- the existing [polaris](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polaris) is renamed to [polaris-chivalric-tragedy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polaris-chivalric-tragedy), as inclusion of part of the game's subtitle is enough to make it definitively unique and this only affects 9 questions as of this posting
- the French [Polaris RPG](https://rpggeek.com/rpgfamily/17710/polaris-french-rpg) can have [polaris](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polaris) or [polaris-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polaris-rpg). The game apparently has three editions with pretty significant changes between 2nd and 3rd (wait a minute...) so potentially warrants [polaris-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polaris-3e)/[polaris-rpg-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polaris-rpg-3e).
- the 2004 [Polaris](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/601/polaris-english-rpg) can be safely ignored for the Time Being since we don't have any questions about it and given its obscurity/defunctness we're pretty unlikely to have any in the future.

Comment: This seems like a sensible answer. What do I do now? Will it just happen or do I have to put in some sort of request?

Comment: @mwarren The diamond moderation team will act on it. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks, that's great.

Comment: @mwarren Just so we know whether we can really kick the can down the road yet — did you get the French RPG or the 2004 Polaris? (It's fine to say you got the 2004 one if you did, we'll have to cross that bridge sooner or later.)

Comment: @doppelgreener I got the English translation of the French RPG. Published 2016 I think.

Comment: Phew! That is a can we can kick down the road then. :)

Comment: [tag:polaris-3english]